# Simplifying multiple CASE calls inside SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, case, mariadb

I have a `table_a` that has two foreign keys to the primary key of table `options`.

I `SELECT` based on `@_aValue` being equal to either of those `options` primary keys in `table_a`. If I stop there, I get a table that has two sets of options for each row in table a. I am only interested in the options that have a primary key equal to `@_aValue`, so only one set of those options, but I don't know in advance which of the two values in `table_a` this would pertain to. Also, I am interested in retrieving all rows in the order they are in the database, which in my opinion would make two queries whose results would have to be sorted less than ideal. I have implemented a solution that works, but I think it is pretty inefficient, since it  performs the same `CASE` comparison multiple times for each row:

```
SELECT
    (CASE a.a_id_1 WHEN @_aValue THEN options_a.value_1 ELSE options_b.value_1 END) AS value_1,
    (CASE a.a_id_1 WHEN @_aValue THEN options_a.value_2 ELSE options_b.value_2 END) AS value_2,
    (CASE a.a_id_1 WHEN @_aValue THEN options_a.value_3 ELSE options_b.value_3 END) AS value_3,
FROM table_a AS a
INNER JOIN options AS options_a
    ON a.a_id_1 = options_a.options_id
INNER JOIN connection_details AS details_b
    ON a.a_id_2 = options_b.options_id
WHERE a.a_id_1 = @_aValue
    OR a.a_id_2 = @_aValue;
```

There are actually more of those `CASE` comparisons in my current version. Is there a way to do the comparison once, and depending on that select either values from `options_a` or values from `options_b`? Ideally the solution would conform to the standard, but if that is not possible, I need it to work in current versions of MySQL and MariaDB 5.3.

Comment: You cannot retrieve rows "in the order they are in the database" other than coincidentally. Neither can you make the DBMS keep them "in" an order. Of course, you can write your query to make it easy for the DBMS to use a sorted index or features of a storage engine if it chooses.

Comment: That CASE comparison costs nothing compared to pulling the rows/indices for the joins. Suggest you measure. Also compare to the suggested solutions. (Always measure to justify & check optimizing.) Yours is straightforward both for humans and the DBMS. Also index appropriately.  Also try https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can get rid of the conditional logic.  But, I think that you can simplify the query a bit.  The first idea is to use `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`

```
SELECT COALESCE(options_a.value_1, options_b.value_1) AS value_1,
       COALESCE(options_a.value_2, options_b.value_2) AS value_2,
       COALESCE(options_a.value_3, options_b.value_3) AS value_3
FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN
     options options_a
     ON a.a_id_1 = options_a.options_id AND
        a.a_id_1 = @_aValue LEFT JOIN
     connection_details details_b
     ON a.a_id_2 = options_b.options_id AND
        a.a_id_1 <> @_aValue
WHERE @_aValue IN (a.a_id_1, a.a_id_2);
```

Actually, there *is* a simpler way:

```
SELECT o.value_1, o.value_2, o.value_3 AS value_3
FROM table_a a JOIN
     ((SELECT 'a' as which, oa.options_id, oa.value_1, oa.value_2, oa.value_3
       FROM options_a oa
       WHERE options_id = @_aValue
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT 'b' as which, cd.options_id, cd.value_1, cd.value_2, cd.value_3
       FROM connection_details cd
       WHERE options_id <> @_aValue
      )
     ) o
     ON a.a_id_1 = @_aValue or a.a_aid_2 = o.options_id
 WHERE @_aValue IN (a.a_id_1, a.a_id_2);
```

(I think I have that `on` condition correct, although I'm a bit concerned about the `WHERE`.)

For the `union all`, you can use `*` if the two tables have exactly the same format.

Comment: Awesome, lots to learn! I'll be experimenting with both of your suggestions.